# Tool to automatically fill defined polygons on an image

Tags: image-processing, graphic-design

I would like to ask if there is an automatic graphic tool to fill polygons on an image? My problem concerns in particular that each polygon of one type should have the same color.

I would like to obtain similar results as shown in the picture attached to this question. It would also be perfect if there would be a possibility to obtain the distribution of these polygons, based on the colors.

[image: Tesselated polygons]

It can be either for Windows or any Linux distribution. It would be perfect if the software is open access or is a part/plugin to Corel, etc. If it comes to paid solutions, I would have to contact my boss, but at this moment we did not consider this case.

Comment: What type is the given image? Is it pixel graphics or vector graphics? If pixel graphics, is it black&white? Is it compressed?

Comment: We can generate the image to be either pixel graphics or vector graphics, also it can be B&W. It will depend on what would be easier to post-process.